# Twilio Flex server side event callback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I am trying to intercept Twilio/Flex events like task created, accepted, call put on hold, etc. I set my Workspace's **Event Callback URL** and I also hooked up the **Status Callback URL** on my Phone #.

And so far that gives me:

- Task related events like `created`, `reservation.accepted`
- Call ended event

What I am missing is events like Call put on hold/unhold, call muted. I know that I can tap into Flex's Actions framework through a React UI plugin, but I would like to keep this server side.